# sqoop hangs when importing a table from sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import a simple table into hive from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

```
Hadoop version - CDH3U3
Sqoop version - 1.3.0-cdh3u3
$SQOOP_HOME/lib - sqljdbc4.jar
$SQOOP_HOME/lib - sqoop-sqlserver-1.0.jar
$SQOOP_CONF_DIR/managers.d/mssqoop-sqlserver

Windows firewall - disabled
Linux IPTables - disabled
```

My import command is -

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.1.47;username=sa;password=asdf1234;database=test' --table bruce --hive-import --verbose
```

I don't see any error messages, but it just hangs forever.  If I look in the SQL Server Activity Monitor, I can see that there is a process being created.

Here is the sqoop output -

```
[root@sc-qa-test-01 bruce]# ./sqoop_test_sqlserver.sh<br>
Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.<br>
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Added factory com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory specified by /usr/lib/sqoop/conf/managers.d/mssqoop-sqlserver<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 INFO SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory: Using Microsoft's SQL Server - Hadoop Connector<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManager@15aaf0b3<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation<br>
12/09/27 15:37:58 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.<br><br>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using Microsoft SQL Connector for Sqoop. As a first step, I would recommend turning it off and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.1.47:<port_number>/test --table bruce --username sa --password asdf1234 --hive-import --hive-table <table_in_hive> --verbose
```

Where table_in_hive is dynamically created